# Why do I get an error when running an sqldf query in R 3.3.3?

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I am running `sqldf` using a WITH clause that works fine in R 3.6.3 but not in R 3.3.3.

Results using R 3.6.3:

```
sqldf("WITH cte_a AS (SELECT cyl, avg(mpg) FROM mtcars group by cyl) SELECT * from cte_a")
#  cyl avg(mpg)
#1   4 26.66364
#2   6 19.74286
#3   8 15.10000
```

Results using R 3.3.3:

```
sqldf("WITH cte_a AS (SELECT cyl, avg(mpg) FROM mtcars group by cyl) SELECT * from cte_a")
#-----
Loading required package: tcltk
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  near "WITH": syntax error
In addition: Warning message:
Quoted identifiers should have class SQL, use DBI::SQL() if the caller performs the quoting.
```

Any help getting the R 3.3.3 query to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason why you're using such an old version of R?

Comment: I don't know how much interest there will be in trying to analyze errors in a flagrantly out-of-date version of R especially when there is no documentation of versions of either pkg:sqldf or the underlying SQL engine. Current version of R is 4.2.0 and R 3.6.3 is a couple of years out of service. (I get no error with current versions of R and sqldf, so maybe the answer is just "do your update".)

Comment: The current version of sqldf has been around since 2017, which is kind of remarkable. I'm guessing that between your R 3.3.3 installation of `sqldf` and your 3.6.3 update that you failed to execute `update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE)` so you are still using sqldf 0.4-10 and perhaps RSQLite 1.0 when the current versions are 0.4-11 and 2.0 respectively. (And you might not need to update R, although why you would not do so is still a mystery.)

Comment: @IRTFM - thanks for the response and information. The customer thought he had to use 3.3.3 because he was missing a library in 3.6.3. He has since installed the required 3.6.3 library, and it's all good now.

Comment: common table expressions were added in sqlite 3.8.3 and various upgrades were made in subsequent versions.  Check what version of sqlite is being used: `sqldf("select sqlite_version()")` .